# Traceless Tensors in $SU(3)$, Georgi's Lie Algebras

Tags: group-representations, tensor-calculus, lie-algebra

I'm doing a self-study through Georgi's Lie Algebra's in Particle Physics and there is a ''note without proof'' in the book that I have not managed to see through myself. In Section 10.3, Georgi states that, in the $(n,m)$ representation of $SU(3)$ the highest weight has the property of being traceless:

$$\delta_{j_1}^{i_1}{v_H}_{i_1\cdots i_n}^{j_1\cdots j_m}=0,$$

and that this property is preserved under $v_H \rightarrow T_av_H$. Given the transformation rule:

$$T_av_{i_1\cdots i_n}^{j_1\cdots j_m}=\sum_{l=1}^m[T_a]_k^{j_l}v_{i_1\cdots i_n}^{j_1\cdots k\cdots j_m}-\sum_{l=1}^n[T_a]_{i_l}^kv_{i_1\cdots k\cdots i_n}^{j_1\cdots j_m}.$$

Georgi further claims that any state in the $(n,m)$ representation shares the tracless property due to the minus sign in the above definition $and$ due to the traclessness of the $T_a$'s. It seems to me that to show this one could proceed inductively starting with the highest weight $v_H$ and at each step use traclessness of the previous weight. I cannot see how the tracelessness of the $T_a$'s comes into the proof. Has any one worked this out explicitly using $Tr(T_a)=0$? If so, some guidance as to this step would be much appreciated.